# A system of differential equations involving limits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $u(t)=(u_1(t),u_2(t))$ be the unique solution of the problem:

$\frac{d}{dx}(u(t))=Au(t)$, $t\gt0$

$u(0)=u_0$

where $u_{0}=(1,1)$ and $A$ is a symmetric $2$ into $2$ matrix such that $tr(A)\lt0$ and $det(A)\gt0$.

Evaluate:
                   $lim_{t\to\infty} u_1(t)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Determine the signs of the two eigenvalues of $A$ from its description.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What are the properties of symmetric real matrices? Are them diagonalizable or not?

Comment: The condition of being symmetric here is not necessary.

Comment: We know that the sum of the eigenvalues of $A$ is negative and the product of them is positive, right?

Comment: I could find out the two eigen values, one of which is negative and tends to zero when "t" goes to infinity. What about the other eigen value which is positive?

Comment: why do you say the other eigenvalue is positive? Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
 -1 &   1 \\ 
  0  &  -2
\end{pmatrix}$$ $tr(A)=-3, \det(A)=2, \lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}$...